# How to Highlight the GWT TextBox

Tags: java, gwt, highlight, gwt2, enter

I need to highlight the `TextBox` when I press the "*enter*" key. I have piece of code for the `KeyPress` event but I don't know how to highlight the textbox.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a class in your CSS like

```
.highlight input {
  background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

then add the class dynamically in your handler

```
someWidget.addStyleName("highlight");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you press the key the textbox will be highlighted, this is the code:

```
    @Override
    public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event)
    {
       if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) 
        {

         textBox.addStyleName("highlight");
        }
    }
```

Add this to your .css file:

```
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  background-color:#FF0000;
}
```